# VIM: How can i refresh directory with vim?

Tags: vim, editor

```
vim .
```

I have renamed some folders in current directory(.).

Now how can I refresh this directory in vim?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the command `:edit` to reload the current file/dir listing.

Answer (score 10):

From the [docs](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pi_netrw.html#netrw-ctrl-l):

> To refresh either a local or remote directory listing, press ctrl-l
>   (<c-l>) or hit the <cr> when atop the ./ directory entry in the
>   listing.  One may also refresh a local directory by using ":e .".

Comment: @guru No, it's the lower-case `L`